# What do you call someone interested in learning many languages?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What do you call a person who is interested in many languages? I think *linguist* and *polyglot* refer to a person who is already well-versed. I need a word for a person who is just interested and starting off to be a linguist in the future.

Comment: You call a person interested in many languages a person interested in many languages.

Comment: Borrowing the punch line of an old joke, such a person is not likely American.

Answer (score 5):

Linguaphile, which is defined as: *a language and word lover.*

or possibly, language enthusiast/aficionado/junkie/buff.

Answer (score 3):

You could call them an

> aspiring polyglot.

The definition of [aspiring](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/aspiring) from ODO is:

> Directing one's hopes or ambitions towards becoming a specified type of person.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the term [**language freak**](http://www.lexiophiles.com/english/are-you-a-language-freak).

"[**language minded**](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/2013-03-04/features/ct-tribu-words-work-national-grammar-day-20130304_1_national-grammar-day-martha-brockenbrough-grammartini)" might also work for what you're looking for.